# More dense layers with heavy dropouts or fewer layers with light dropouts?

Tags: neural-networks, dropout

I'm trying to build a network. While creating the fully connected part in the last, Which one should we prefer: More layers that regularly reduce with heavy dropouts or fewer layers that reduce drastically with light dropouts?

```
    x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(image_features)
    x = Dropout(0.8)(x)  
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)  
    x = Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)  
    x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
```

or

```
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu')(image_features)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)  
    x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
```

Comment: It's nearly impossible to predict which one would do better on your problem and data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have a good answer, because there's no hard science behind neural network architectures. The usual answer would be to *try both and see which one works better*. A more practical one would be to search for examples of people solving similar problems in the past and try similar solutions to theirs first.